# Redshift select random records but avoid duplicate

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift where I have following records for a sample ID 71082:

```
id       trm_num        start_time
71082   PCMAMGA759551   2012-05-02 09:41:54
71082   PCMAMGA759551   2015-06-02 13:23:39
71082   PCMAMGA759551   2015-09-03 13:23:39
71082   PCMAMGA759551   2015-12-11 07:25:25
71082   PCMAMGA759551   2017-01-10 09:03:22
```

I want to choose only 1 random record for every id.
For this I tried the query :

```
select * from mytable where id=71082 order by random limit 1;
```

it fetched me random record.But the table has 1000s of different ids.How can I modify my query for the other ids?

Answer (score 6):

Use the window function `ROW_NUMBER` with random order per ID:

```
select id, trm_num, start_time
from
(
  select
    id, trm_num, start_time,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by random()) as rn
  from mytable
) numbered
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: just a little note: add the () to random: (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY random())

Comment: @enri: Thank you.